# change the place of Rootview(uitableviewcontroller subclass) in splitview

Tags: ipad, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to change the frame of  rootview controller in splitview or  size of rootview controller or the size of detailview controller.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Apple allows this by default. Take a look at [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) which is more customizable.

You may be able to resize it in the nib but I'm pretty sure Apple has set a standard size for the 2 controllers in the UISplitViewController.

Comment: you are right,i saw this before too  but  can u give me the link or somthing for the explaination of program flow for this because this is little complex for me. and thanx for help.

Comment: @dh14-sl sorry but the only help available for it is here: https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/wiki I haven't used it myself but I've taken a look at the code and it shouldn't be much more complicated than using a UISplitViewController.